# Angular Router pass-thru for some routes

Tags: angular, angular-routing

My server has this mapping:

- `/` serves Angular application which uses routing
- `/admin` serves Django control panel for staff to update the database tables.
- `/api and /api/...` serve REST endpoints for making queries and returning JSON

How can I make Angular Router hand those urls (`/admin` and `/api/...` back to the real server instead of trying to resolve them within the front end application? I've added the items below to the **Routes** list, but it didn't work...

```
export const rootRouterConfig: Routes = [
    {path: 'admin', redirectTo: document.location.origin + '/admin'},
    {path: 'api', redirectTo: document.location.origin + '/api'},
    ... ]
```

Comment: Found this, thought it might be helpful. https://medium.com/@adrianfaciu/using-the-angular-router-to-navigate-to-external-links-15cc585b7b88

Comment: Having faced a similar issue, I know that some of our projects use a hash in the url for this separation (like localhost:4200/#/admin...). But I don't know it well enough to explain here, so it could be something good to research. Good luck! :)

Comment: I'm building my application with base href set to <xyz>, so, all routes with /<xyz>/... are angular routes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on an apache server you could add them to your `.htaccess` file... I have somtheing like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^admin/(.+)?$  backend/admin/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^api/(.+)?$  backend/api/$1 [NC,L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

The last part is the one that redirects to the angular app page (index.html) if nothing else matches (it is actually taken from the angular prod deploy documentation.) in this manner, the Angular application only gets the route if Apache fails.

The Rewrite also works with NginX, but is part of your server config, not the `.htaccess` file and the rule syntax is slightly different in some cases.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using IIS but I'll try something like that... But is there any possible way I can tell Angular that for some routes it should simply step back and let the request be made directly to the server which would have its response rendered normally by the browser? I mean, I'm not expert in Angular, but this seems pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: As @saglamcem stated, if you have a `#` in the URL then the path is never sent to the server, and the routing os 100% Angular. In that case I don't have a clue. If the URL doesn't contain a `#`, then the request is sent to the server. If the path exists, (IE your backend) that should be served, if not, the server's error handling kicks in and throws a 404

Comment: But the urls I'm trying to retrieve contain no #

Comment: That IS strange. I do not have an IIS to test with, but my experience is that without the `#` and a file on the server named `/sample` the server will serve `/sample` (with no route configured in angular for that path ofc. if you have the route in angular, it may not work)